# Determine future timezone transitions

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I need to predict when the next at least 2 timezone transitions will be for a particular timezone.

Java 8 offers the new `java.time` API, specifically `java.time.zone`. `ZoneRules.getTransitions()` looks like exactly what I need however it doesn't list anything beyond the year 2010 for "Australia/Sydney".

What is the most reliable way to determine the next 2 timezone transition's date/time/offset?

Comment: @Thirler you can't spell ;)

Comment: In general this can not be done, because the rules to apply in the future can be changed by governments. They sometimes change at short notice. It should be possible to get the next *know* transitions.

Comment: @Raedwald "in general this can not be done" - can actually be done ... in general!

Comment: I guess what Raedwald meant by "In general this can not be done" is that any such list is only a prediction based on the currently defined rules, but these rules do change from time to time due to political decisions. There is no guarantee that any of these time zone transitions will actually happen, or that the list will be the same tomorrow.

Comment: Note that [the java docs for ZoneRules.getTransitionRules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getTransitionRules--) contains statements like "If the zone does not have daylight savings, or information about future changes is uncertain, then the list will be empty".

Comment: @Hulk i would have thought that obvious but maybe not to all :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method `ZoneRules.getTransitions()` doesn't list all transitions until infinity into the future (obviously). This gets the next two transitions:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney");
ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();

ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition = rules.nextTransition(Instant.now());
System.out.println("Next transition at: " +
        nextTransition.getInstant().atZone(zoneId));

ZoneOffsetTransition nextNextTransition =
        rules.nextTransition(nextTransition.getInstant());
System.out.println("Next transition after that at: " +
        nextNextTransition.getInstant().atZone(zoneId));
```

Output:

> Next transition at: 2016-10-02T03:00+11:00[Australia/Sydney]
>
> Next transition after that at: 2017-04-02T02:00+10:00[Australia/Sydney]

Comment: yes, still surprised 'getTransitions' doesn't at least list all up to today (ie all past) - thanks for the solution, works great.

Comment: `getTransitions()` (or the none existing `getFutureTransitions()`) is the best example I've ever seen of what could have been a useful infinite `Stream`.

Comment: @Thirler It isn't that hard to build an own `getFutureTransitions()` with an infinite `Stream`: `Stream.iterate(rules.nextTransition(Instant.now()), t -> rules.nextTransition(t.getInstant()))`

Comment: The state of `ZoneRules` has two parts - transitions (known historic) accessed via `getTransitions()`, and transition rules (uncertain future) accessed via `getTransitionRules()`. The `nextTransition(Instant)` method glues the two pieces of state together.